# Menu action items goes to overflow menu

Tags: java, android, android-menu

You will have to forgive me, because I am still pretty new to android development. For my android app, I am staying to create a custom menu and place on the tool bar with the java code in a base activity that is extended by the other activities. But for some reason, the menu buttons are hiding in the overflow menu even though there is more than enough room for them to be showing. I feel like my code is correct, but I need to add a reference to something somewhere else that I am missing. Thanks in advance!

[Current toolbar appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np3dP.png)

BaseActivity.java

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResource());

        toolBar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolBar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                setDisplayHomeEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResource();

    public void setDisplayHomeEnabled(boolean b) {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        toolBar.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(int titleId) {
        toolBar.setTitle(titleId);
    }

    public Toolbar getToolBar() {
        return toolBar;
    }
}
```

toolbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main_menu.xml file, add an 'app' tag for showAsAction as I have done below. It worked for me. See if that works for you too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Still having this issue and adding that line gives me a warming "Namespace declaration is never used". Do I have to this somewhere else as well?

Comment: I think you haven't added 'app:showAsAction="always"' attribute as I have done above. A screenshot will be helpful if still not working.